# What does this message on verbose mode mean? I verbose moded my Macbook Air 2017 to see why it takes 20-25 secs from login to desktop

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, startup, kernel-extensions

Specs:

- Macbook Air 2017
- macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- 1.8 GHz Intel Core i5
- 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB

Apps installed:

- Photoshop
- Skype
- VPN
- Spotify
- Google Chrome (this one I only use occasionally to check my SEO game, since it's required for my work. I use primarily Safari.)
- Website Auditor
- Rank Tracker

I've had it for two years. For over a year, I've had this machine dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04 for some computational stuff for my research. Intense programming. For almost 6 months now, I've only been using this computer for web browsing, light photo and video editing, and watching youtube. So I decided to erase the Ubuntu partition, but the problem is that I accidentally wiped everything including the macOS. I have no backup at all.

Anyway, I relied on Internet Recovery to reinstall High Sierra. From there, I updated to Mojave. (Note that I have tried Catalina for 1 week but I hated it since it made everything slower without giving me any major benefits at all).

The point is, even though I started anew, reset my NVRAM, SMC, selected a startup disk, deleted login items, and did everything I read on the internet, it still takes 20-25 seconds from entering my password, to my desktop. It used to get me up and running in less than 15 seconds. So I tried verbose mode.

This is what the slowest point of the verbose mode is:

[image]

and

[image]

Something about kext and trim. Can someone please help me? What should I do?

Comment: When you reinstalled Mojave, did you erase the disk first or did you just go right to “Reinstall macOS?”

Comment: I erased the disk first. And then when I started my computer, there was a folder with "?" on it instead of Apple logo. I had no choice but to go with Internet Recovery to reinstall the original OS the Macbook came when I bought it, which is High Sierra. Then from there, a Mojave upgrade from the Apple website.

Comment: That sounds about right; as you didn't need to reboot after wiping the drive.  So, just to be clear...you installed a clean version of HS, then upgraded to Mojave.  Did you wipe the drive when you upgraded from High Sierra to Mojave?

Comment: @Allan no I didn't

Comment: Restart the Mojave installer, use Disk Utility to wipe the drive.  When done, *quit* Disk Utility; the initial menu will come back.  Select “reinstall macOS.”  When  you do an in place upgrade, remnants of High Sierra get left behind.

Comment: @Allan I'll do all this in recovery mode, right?

Comment: Correct.  Recovery (local) or Internet recovery.  Either works.

Comment: @Allan SOLVED!! Boot time went from 25-30 secs to 15-20 secs!! Thanks a lot 